# Derived category of $\mathcal{D}_X$ modules

Tags: derived-categories, d-modules

Define $D^{\text{#}}_{\bullet}(Mod(\mathcal{D}_X))$ to be the full subcategory of the derived category $D^{\text{#}}(Mod(\mathcal{D}_X))$ of complexes of $\mathcal{D}_X$-modules whose cohomology groups belong to $Mod_{\bullet}(\mathcal{D}_X)$, # = $+,-,b$, $X$ smooth algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$.

Is it true that $D^{\text{#}}_{\bullet}(Mod(\mathcal{D}_X))$ is equivalent to the category $D^{\text{#}}(Mod_{\bullet}(\mathcal{D}_X))$?

It is true that $Mod_{\bullet}(\mathcal{D}_X)$ are closed under kernels, cokernels and extensions because we are working over a Noetherian scheme. However, Kashiwara-Schapira *Category and Sheaves* states the equivalence under one more hypothesis. Apart from the answer, if you can quote any reference I would be glad.

EDIT: I forgot to say that $\bullet =$ quasi coherent modules or coherent modules (a quasi coherent $\mathcal{D}_X$ module is a $\mathcal{D}_X$ modules which is quasi coherent over $\mathcal{O}_X$, instead coherence is over $\mathcal{D}_X$)

Comment: What is $Mod_\bullet$?

Comment: @BugsBunny Forgive me, I added what is $\bullet$

Comment: Did you check https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236245/equivalence-between-a-derived-subcategory-and-a-subcategory-of-the-derived-categ

Comment: IMHO, the answer is UNKNOWN. If there is a good reason for it to be YES, it is known thanks to Exercise on p.153 of Gelfand-Manin or
2.42 and 3.4 of Huybrechts...

Answer (score 2):

I post it as an answer because I found it on a book: Theorem 1.5.7 of *D-Modules, perverse sheaves, and representation theory* by Hotta, Takeuchi, and Tanisaki states that the natural functors give equivalence or categories

$$D^{b}(Mod_{\bullet}(\mathcal{D}_X)) \rightarrow D^{b}_{\bullet}(\mathcal{D}_X)$$

The book says that this result was due to Bernstein, and it can be found *Algebraic D-Modules*, Perspectives in Mathematics, Vol 2, 1987, by Borel, Grivel, Kaup, Haefliger, Malgrange, And Ehlers.

Comment: May I ask if the result is know when $X$ is singular?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. The book I referred to deal with D-modules on smooth varieties.