# Category of $\mathcal{D}$-modules on a singular variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, derived-categories, d-modules

Take $X\to V$ a closed embedding, where $X$ is not necessarily smooth, $V$ is affine and smooth. Define the category $\mathcal{C}$ of $\mathcal{D}$ modules on $X$ to be the full subcategory of $\mathcal{D}$ modules on $V$ with support on $X$.

I want to ask if the inclusion $D(\mathcal{C})\to D_\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{D}_V\text{-mod})$ is an equivalence (where $D_\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{D}_V\text{-mod})$ is the full subcategory of $D(\mathcal{D}_V\text{-mod})$ consisting complexes with cohomologies in $\mathcal{C}$). I believe it is. In fact for what I really need, I only need the inclusion to be fully faithful, but nevertheless it should be an equivalence. The derived category is the one with either quasi-coherent or coherent objects, and should be bounded. Note when $X$ is smooth, this is just a version of Kashiwara's Theorem.

What we know: $\mathcal{C}$ is thick/Serre, $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}_V\text{-mod}$ are Grothedieck (so has enough injectives).

There is a potential useful theorem in Kashiwara-Schapira Category and Sheaves, Theorem 13.2.8, but I don't know how to show the conditions. Also, these overflow questions can be useful: [Equivalence between a derived subcategory and a subcategory of the derived category](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236245/equivalence-between-a-derived-subcategory-and-a-subcategory-of-the-derived-categ)

[Derived category of $\mathcal{D}_X$ modules](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296437/derived-category-of-mathcald-x-modules?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Edited later: Actually there is more to ask: similar to [Derived category of $\mathcal{D}_X$ modules](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296437/derived-category-of-mathcald-x-modules?noredirect=1&lq=1), is the same result still true for singular $X$, because normally Kashiwara's theorem is stated using 'the other' version of derived category instead of the version I am using (and they turn out to be the same in the smooth case), but I probably don't need this...

Comment: any suggestion will help

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that we're dealing with bounded-below complexes, as I'm most familiar with those.

Denote by $\Gamma_X$ the sections-supported-on-$X$ functor, i.e. 
$$\Gamma(U, \Gamma_X(\mathcal{F})) = \ker\left(\Gamma(U; \mathcal{F}) \xrightarrow{\text{restriction}} \Gamma(U\setminus X; \mathcal{F})\right).$$
Let $\mathcal{M}^\bullet$ be a bounded-below complex of $\mathcal{D}_V$-modules whose cohomology is supported on $X$. It suffices to show that $\mathcal{M}^\bullet$ is quasi-isomorphic to a complex of objects in $\mathcal{C}$.

I claim that the inclusion $i^\bullet\colon \Gamma_X(\mathcal{M}^\bullet) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{M}^\bullet$ is a quasi-isomorphism. I do this by induction on the cohomological degree $p$.

When $p\ll 0$, both complexes vanish, so $H^p\Gamma_X(\mathcal{M}^\bullet) = H^p(\mathcal{M}^\bullet) = 0$, and therefore $H^p(i^\bullet)$ is trivially an isomorphism.

Assume we know that $H^{p-1}(i^\bullet)$ is an isomorphism. Consider the short exact sequence
$$0 \to \Gamma_X(\mathcal{M}^\bullet) \to \mathcal{M}^\bullet \to \mathcal{M}^\bullet/\Gamma_X(\mathcal{M}^\bullet) \to 0.$$
This gives rise to an exact sequence
$$  H^{p-1}(\mathcal{M}^\bullet) \to  H^{p-1}(\mathcal{M}^\bullet/\Gamma_X(\mathcal{M}^\bullet)) \to H^{p-1}(\mathcal{M}^\bullet/\Gamma_X(\mathcal{M}^\bullet)) \to H^p(\Gamma_X(\mathcal{M}^\bullet)) \to H^p(\mathcal{M}^\bullet) \to  H^p(\mathcal{M}^\bullet/\Gamma_X(\mathcal{M}^\bullet)).\tag{1}
$$
By the induction hypothesis, the first map is an isomorphism, so (1) gives the exact sequence
$$
0\to H^{p-1}(\mathcal{M}^\bullet/\Gamma_X(\mathcal{M}^\bullet)) \xrightarrow{a} H^p(\Gamma_X(\mathcal{M}^\bullet)) \xrightarrow{H^p(i^{\bullet})} H^p(\mathcal{M}^\bullet) \xrightarrow{b}  H^p(\mathcal{M}^\bullet/\Gamma_X(\mathcal{M}^\bullet)).\tag{2}
$$
For each $q$, no non-zero section of $\mathcal{M}^q/\Gamma_X(\mathcal{M}^q)$ vanishes outside of $X$ (prove this!), so the same is true of each $H^q(\mathcal{M}^\bullet/\Gamma_X(\mathcal{M}^\bullet))$. On the other hand, *every* non-zero section of $H^q(\mathcal{I}^\bullet)$ and $H^q(\Gamma_X(\mathcal{I}^\bullet))$  vanishes outside of $X$ (the first by hypothesis and the second because by the definition of $\Gamma_X$). Therefore, $a$ and $b$ must be the zero map. Hence, $H^p(i^{\bullet})$ is an isomorphism.

**Edit 1:** To see fully faithfulness: $\Gamma_X\colon \mathcal D_V\text{-mod} \to \mathcal{C}$ preserves injectives (because it is right adjoint to the inclusion functor, which is fully faithful). <strike>Therefore, the hom sets in $D^+(\mathcal C)$ and $D^+_X(\mathcal D_V)$ are computed in the same way.</strike>

**Edit 2 (2019/10/06):** Using the following fact, along with the non-crossed-out part of Edit 1, I am going to prove fully faithfulness.

> **Fact.** Although in general, a morphism $u$ between bounded below complexes with $H^n(u)=0$ for all $n$ is not necessarily $0$ in the derived category, if such a morphism $u$ maps between complexes of injectives, then it *is* $0$. (See, e.g., the proof of Prop. 1.7.10 from Kashiwara and Schapira's *Sheaves on Manifolds*).

Let $\mathcal{M}^\bullet, \mathcal{N}^\bullet$ be bounded below complexes of objects of $\mathcal{C}$. Choose $\mathcal{D}_V$-injective resolutions $\mathcal{I}^\bullet,\mathcal{J}^\bullet$ of $\mathcal{M}^\bullet, \mathcal{N}^\bullet$, respectively. Because $\Gamma_X(\mathcal{M}^\bullet)=\mathcal{M}^\bullet$ (as $\mathcal{M}^\bullet$ is a complex of guys in $\mathcal{C}$), the resolving quasi-isomorphism $\mathcal{M}^\bullet \to \mathcal{I}^\bullet$ factors through the natural inclusion $\Gamma_X(\mathcal{I}^\bullet) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{I}^\bullet$. Hence, because by the above, the natural inclusion $\Gamma_X(\mathcal{I}^\bullet) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{I}^\bullet$ is a quasi-isomorphism, we get a quasi-isomorphism (i.e. a resolution) $\mathcal{M}^\bullet\to \Gamma_X(\mathcal{I}^\bullet)$. But $\Gamma_X(\mathcal{I}^\bullet)$ is a complex of $\mathcal{C}$-injectives, so we in fact have a $\mathcal{C}$-injective resolution
$$ \mathcal{M}^\bullet\to \Gamma_X(\mathcal{I}^\bullet)$$
of $\mathcal{M}^\bullet$. Similarly, 
$$\mathcal{N}^\bullet\to \Gamma_X(\mathcal{J}^\bullet)$$
is a $\mathcal{C}$-injective resolution of $\mathcal{N}^\bullet$.

Replacing $\mathcal{M}^\bullet$ and $\mathcal{N}^\bullet$ with $\Gamma_X(\mathcal{I}^\bullet)$ and $\Gamma_X(\mathcal{J}^\bullet)$, resp., it is enough to show that

1. for every morphism $u^\bullet\colon \Gamma_X(\mathcal{I}^\bullet)\to \Gamma_X(\mathcal{J}^\bullet)$, there exists a unique (in $D^+_X(\mathcal{D}_V)$) morphism $v^\bullet\colon \mathcal{I}^\bullet\to \mathcal{J}^\bullet$ extending $u^\bullet$; and
2. if $u^\bullet=0$ in $\mathcal{D}^+(\mathcal{C})$, then $v^\bullet=0$ in in $D^+_X(\mathcal{D}_V)$.

Let $i^\bullet,j^\bullet$ be, resp., the inclusions $\Gamma_X(\mathcal{I}^\bullet) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{I}^\bullet$ and $\Gamma_X(\mathcal{J}^\bullet) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{J}^\bullet$. The existence of $v^\bullet$ is because everything in town is injective. Then 2. and the remaining part of 1. follow from the Fact together with the equation
$$ v^\bullet\circ i^\bullet = j^\bullet\circ u^\bullet.$$

Comment: how do you show fully faithfulness? is that automatic?

Comment: @FunctionOfX see my edit

Comment: Sorry, I am not understanding why $\Gamma_X: \mathcal{D}_X$-mod$\to \mathcal{C}$ preserve injectives. In fact, what is $\mathcal{D}_X$

Comment: oh you mean D_V?

Comment: @FunctionOfX shoot! Yes, I do! Good catch. It’s fixed now.

Comment: and do you mean right adjoint and exact rather than equivalence?

Comment: @FunctionOfX sorry again. I meant fully faithful.

Comment: no problem, in fact thank you so much for your answer, one last question, should the word left adjoint be replaced by right adjoint? I believe it is the right adjoint for closed embedding at least in the smooth case.

Comment: @FunctionOfX ugh! You’re totally right!

Comment: sorry one last question... surely we need preservation of injective resolutions rather than just injectives...

Comment: @FunctionOfX since $\Gamma_X$ preserves injectives, I can always resolve an object of $\mathcal C$ by injectives in $\mathcal D_V$-mod

Comment: @ Avi Steiner sorry to bother you again, how does D act on $\Gamma_X$

Comment: @FunctionOfX $\Gamma_X(\mathcal{M})$ is a $\mathcal{D}_V$-submodule of $\mathcal{M}$. One way to see this (at least in the algebraic category, where I feel much more confident about all this stuff) is that $\Gamma_X(\mathcal{M})$ is the sheaf of sections of $\mathcal{M}$ killed by a power of the defining ideal of $X$; now use that this property is preserved under multiplication by elements of $\mathcal{D}_V$.

Comment: thanks! I still don't quite see how preserve injectives (not necessarily exact) help with computing hom sets, if will be great if you can spell out the detail!

Comment: @FunctionOfX So, I was apparently thinking in the crossed-out part that $\Gamma_X$ fixes $\mathcal{D}_V$-injectives, or maybe that one can always resolve by $\mathcal{D}_V$-injectives for which this is true. However, I have no reason to believe either of those statements, hence the crossed-out things. Anyway, I hopefully salvaged things correctly in my latest edit. Let me know!

Comment: @ avi steiner, thank you. Yeah, the crossed out part was exactly my confusion. D Gaitsgory actually proved this in this paper CRYSTALS AND D-MODULES (prop 4.7.3). The paper uses crystals (which i am not very familiar with), but the proof itself actually doesn't deal with it too much (even though I don't claim I understand it fully).

Comment: @FunctionOfX ah. That paper. I have it on my list of to-reads for if I ever learn DAG

Comment: yeah... i dont understand it, but it is a result we can quote. I only found it out a few days ago. Thank you so much for your answer.